# Rewrite with Nginx and PHP fastcgi still sends old request_uri to backend (php and symfony)

Tags: php, symfony1, url-rewriting, nginx, fastcgi

I am trying to migrate a php-website running the symfony framework to nginx and php over fastcgi.

It all works well usining the Symfony howto from http://wiki.nginx.org/ but I run into trouble with a custom rewrite rule.

My goal is to rewrite urls of of the form **/aaaa** to **/view/shorthand/aaaa**. The request should then be handeled by php and symfony.

Old apache rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-f]+)$ index.php/view/shorthand/$1 [L]
```

Nginx rules i have tried:

```
rewrite ^/([0-9a-f]+)$ /view/shorthand/$1 break;
rewrite ^/([0-9a-f]+)$ /index.php/view/shorthand/$1 break;
```

They all get sent to fastcgi but the **request_uri** still seems to be **/aaaa** since I get this error:

```
FastCGI sent in stderr: "Action "aaaa/index" does not exist" while reading response header from upstream
```

I have also tried using try_files without any luck. Please advice.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issues right now, have you managed to resolve it?

Answer (score 14):

The problem is in default FastCGI variables set (`fastcgi_params` config file), where `REQUEST_URI` is equal to nginx's `$request_uri`. But if you carefully read [Nginx documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#variables), you will notice the difference between `$request_uri` and `$uri` variables.

- `$request_uri` = full original request URI (with arguments)
- `$uri` = current URI in request, normalized

The value of `$uri` may change during request processing, e.g. when doing internal redirects, or when using index files. So, if you want to fix `REQUEST_URI` value before it passed to PHP, just change `$request_uri` to `$uri?$args` in `fastcgi_params`.

It's the way Nginx lead developer Igor Sysoev [recommends in the official mailing list](http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?21,58585,59005#msg-59005).

Comment: `+1` for the nice explanation :)