# Rewrite request_uri fail

Tags: nginx, php

I have nginx + php-fpm, and I would like to have $_SEVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/process', when I try to access '/rest/proccess'. So I just created such config for nginx:

```
location /rest/ {
    root   /var/www/php;

    rewrite ^/rest/(.*)$ /$1 break;

    fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/index.php;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}
```

But it does not work, in php I have $_SEVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/rest/process'.

What I'm doing wrong?

Thnx

UPD: It seems that rewrite rule rewrites only $document_uri, but not $request_uri, so $_SEVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/rest/process' and $_SEVER['DOCUMENT_URI'] == '/process'

Comment: hmm, url have schema http://... or ftp://....

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rewrite with Nginx and PHP fastcgi still sends old request\_uri to backend (php and symfony)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8339183/rewrite-with-nginx-and-php-fastcgi-still-sends-old-request-uri-to-backend-php-a)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change your rewrite to:

```
rewrite ^/rest/(.+)$ $scheme://$host/$1;
```